# Javascript - Undefined object in an object

Tags: javascript, object

I know there are a lot of similar questions to this one, and I've looked through quite a few but haven't managed to find my answer.

I have created a custom object called `destination`:

```
function destination() {
    var city = "";
    var flightNumber = "";
    var type = "";
}
```

I have then created a second custom object, and one of the properties of that object is of type `destination`:

```
function plane() {
    var flightNumber = "";
    var otherCity = new destination();
    var status = "";
    var taxiRoute = [];
    var airRoute = "";
    var heading = 0;
    var speed = 0;
    var left = 0;
    var top = 0;
    var height = 0;
    var width = 0;
    var dx = 0;
    var dy = 0;
}
```

However, whenever I try to access any of the properties of type `destination` using something like:

```
aPlanes[0].otherCity.city;
```

where `aPlanes` is an array of `plane()` objects, I get the undefined error message in the browser console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'city' of undefined

Is anyone able to point out where I'm going wrong?  It's driving me mad!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a wrong [class definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new#Object_type_and_object_instance). You need [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) and not local variables with var declaration.

```
function Destination() {
    this.city = "";
    this.flightNumber = "";
    this.type = "";
}
```

BTW, I suggest to use the standard for class declarations with upper case first letter.

Comment: Thank you so much, such a simple answer.